# Integral representation of ${}_3 F_2$ allowing negative integers

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

There exist many integral representations of the generalised hypergeometric function ${}_3 F_2$ but these are all assuming that the entries are positive integers. I have a problem involving,

$${}_3F_2 \left(-n, 1+\frac{a}{2}, -\frac{a}{2}; 1, -b; 1\right)$$

where $0 \leq n \leq \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \rfloor$, $b \geq \frac{a}{2}$ and $a$ is even. In this case it is well-defined, since the numerator reaches zero before the denominator, and you get a polynomial in $n$. However, I can't use any of these integral representations since things like $\Gamma(-b)$ appear. Are there integral representations that allow for negative integer entries in the hypergeometric function?

As an example of what goes wrong, if you look at the [Euler's integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Euler%27s_integral_transform) it would give,

$${}_3F_2 \left(-n, 1+\frac{a}{2}, -\frac{a}{2}; 1, -b; 1\right) = \frac{\Gamma(-b)}{\Gamma(-a/2)\Gamma(a/2-b)} \int_0^1 {}_2 F_1(\dots) \dots$$

and that prefactor evaluates to zero for even $a$ (or indeterminate if you evaluate $b$ first) which is obviously not right since ${}_3 F_2$ is not zero.